# How to prevent inconsistent OperationalError in pyodbc?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert, connection

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows (linux Docker container in the future after deployment)
- python 3.9, SQLAlchemy 1.4.19, pyodbc 4.0.30

I'm using SQL Alchemy python module to communicate to Azure SQL. Workflow creates temporary tables, insert data to it, drops production tables, renames temporary tables to production names. Most of the times it works as expected, but sometimes I get this error in the middle of inserting rows, like I would lose connection with database:

> OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)

This is my connector super class:

```
class DatabaseConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection_params = None

        self.query_params = None

        self.query = None

        self.engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://', creator=self.connection, echo=False, fast_executemany=True)

        self.sql_path = Path().cwd() / "sql"

    def connection(self):
        return pyodbc.connect(self.connection_params)

    def set_connection_params(self, connection_params: tuple):
        connection_params = connection_params
        self.connection_params = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' + \
                                 'SERVER={};' \
                                 'DATABASE={};' \
                                 'UID={};' \
                                 'PWD={}'.format(*connection_params)
    def set_query_params(self, params_list: list):
        self.query_params = params_list
```

Comment: 08S01 Communication link failure mostly occurs due to network issues. Can you try by adding “connection timeout =30” in your connection string? With this server can wait for 30 seconds for the connection before generating error.